# Best practices in securing Oracle Standard edition one

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, security, best-practices

I have a database server with Oracle Standard Edition One. I'm interested what are the best practices to secure Oracle? I have Java web application installed in the same server. The Java application uses Oracle to store data.

Best Wishes
Peter

Answer (score 1):

You may want to work through the Oracle [Project Lockdown](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/index-087388.html) documentation.  It takes you though the security process with increasing levels of security over time.